# How do I see what server I am connected to in OSX (To be specific, NAS drive not server)

Tags: networking, nas

Our office uses a NAS drive as a 'server'. Our machines are connected via a wired connection in offce. I'm trying to establish whether my iMac is (already) connected to it via afp or sms. Is there a command prompt or something I can use which will give me the address I am currently connected to? So it would return something like 'afp://000.000.00.00'

Apologies if this is a stupid question, I'm more of a Windows user and not really versed in OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Get Info' on the root of the share or any file down the path -  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>i</kbd>  .

It will tell you the path & protocol [also the format, lower down, if you use the root.]

[image]

These days, btw, it will tend to default to SMB rather than AFP, as the latter is deprecated if not yet totally abandoned.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin - looks like I'm connecting currently via AFP which might explain a few connection issues..